# HTML website Border around images

Tags: css, html, web

I set up a smaller gallery of pictures in my web proj website:

http://younani.com/finalsite/gallery.html

To me the way the pictures sit do not look like nice. Is there a way to put borders inbetween the pictures and around it. Make it look more organize? I tried to border it but it just moved the pictures all over the script and I wasnt able to put borders in between.

CSS:

```
#header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1150px;
}


#container {

     background-color: #FAFAFA;
     color: #003300;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-position: center; background-size: cover;

}

#h2 {text-align: center;}

#container {
          margin-right:auto;
          margin-left:auto;
          background-image:url('backgroundflower5.jpg');
          min-width:1000px;
          max-width:1000px;
          padding:0px 70px 50px 70px;
          border:1px ridge #000000;
          border-radius:20px;
          -webkit-box-shadow:inset -3px -3px -3px 3px #18cad0;
          -moz-box-shadow:inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
          box-shadow:inset -3px -3px 1px .9px black;
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        #container div {

        }


        #header {}


#center2 {
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
            min-width: 200px; width: 494px; border-radius:8px; 
        }

#center2 img
        {
        opacity:0.5;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }

#center2 img:hover
        {
        opacity:1.0;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
        }



#centerO {float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;

            min-width: 200px; font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; background-color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 494px; border-radius:8px; text-align: left; box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px 1px #000000; }

#center {box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px 1px #000000;}

        #left,
        #center,
        #right {
            float: left; margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;



            min-width: 200px;
        }

        #center {font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif; background-color: #FFFFFF;
            width: 494px; border-radius:8px; text-align: center;
        } 

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }

#right2 {float: left;
            margin: 10px 0 10px 20px; border: 0px;

            min-width: 200px;}

#right { font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; border-radius:8px; background-color: #FFFFFF; box-shadow:inset 1px 1px 10px 1px #000000; text-align: center;}

#left a {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
        display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,
        #ffffff 0%,
        #2a07ed);
    background: -webkit-gradient(
        linear, left top, left bottom, 
        from(#ffffff),
        to(#2a07ed));
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(026,020,219,1);
    -webkit-box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(026,020,219,1);
    box-shadow:
        0px 3px 11px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(026,020,219,1);
    text-shadow:
        0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
        0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}





figure{}

#left a:link { background-color: #E6E6E6; }
#left a:visited { background-color: #E6E6E6; }
#left a:hover {border: 3px inset #333333; }

#left ul { list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding-left: 0; }



#footer { text-align: center; font-family: Audimat;
    clear: both; width:38%;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color:white;
        text-align:center; margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto; }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

   <title>Younani Flower's</title>

   <meta charset="utf-8">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="final.css" />

</head>



<body>
<div id="header"><img src="header88.png" alt="header" height="200" width="1150" /></div>
<div id="container" class="clearfix"><!-- Header --> <!-- Left Column -->
<div id="left">
<ul>
<li><a href="finalindex.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
<li><a href="occasions.html">Occasions</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<!-- Center Column -->
<div id="center2"><a href="Meadowthistlebig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="Meadowthistle.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="saffronbig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="saffron.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="dahliasbig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="dahlias.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a><a href="bachelorbuttonbig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="bachelorbutton.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a><a href="dahliasbig.jpg" target="_blank">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a><a href="hrysanthemumbig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="hrysanthemum.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a><a href="dahliasbig.jpg" target="_blank">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a><a href="PinkLilybig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="PinkLily.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a><a href="dahliasbig.jpg" target="_blank"></a><a href="pinkrosesbig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="pinkroses.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a><a href="dahliasbig.jpg" target="_blank">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><a href="RectifiedFlowers.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="RectifiedFlowers.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a><a href="dahliasbig.jpg" target="_blank">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a><a href="rhodendronbig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="rhodendron.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a><a href="gazaniadaisybig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="gazaniadaisy.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="GreenFlower.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="GreenFlower3.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="nellwernerbig.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="nellwerner.jpg" height="113" width="150" alt="" /> </a></div>
<!-- Right Column -->
<div id="right">
<p><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Meaning of Flower Colors</span><strong></strong></strong></p>
<p>Pink&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Caring</p>
<p>Purple&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Royalty</p>
<p>Red&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Declaration of love</p>
<p>Yellow&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Hopelessly in love</p>
<p>Violet&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Faithfulness</p>
<p>Red &amp; White&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Unity</p>
<p>Bronze&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Excitement</p>
<p>Blue&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;loyalty</p>
<p>Green&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Growth</p>
<p>Orange&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Warmth</p>
<p>Indigo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Emotions</p>
<p>White&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Purity</p>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="footer" class="clear">
<div class="nav"><b><a href="finalindex.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="occasions.html">Occasions</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- #container -->
<p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi there. I don't mean any offense, but you might want to backtrack a few steps and consider redesigning the site so it looks pleasing with its bare essentials. This looks like the best 1996 had to offer. Try reading some articles on modern web design practices. Good luck :)

Comment: you can see http://themeforest.net/popular_item/by_category?category=site-templates to check popular design and current market trad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this css**

```
#center2  a img {
    border: 2px solid red;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 125px;
}
```

**Results is**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try

```
#center2 > a {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
#center2 img {
opacity: 0.5;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
border: solid 2px #F0FF49;
float: left;
margin: 6px;
}
```

[image]